# Azure mvc web app deploy with 2 dbcontexts and class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, azure-web-app-service

Hi guys i am trying to deploy mvc application to azure. so far, ive done half of the work. so, main web application with AplicationDbContext is were my Identity2.0 tables are for user and roles and so on. Now, i have DAL class library for model and QuizContext for the rest of the application. I what to use one instance of database for storing these two contexts and as u can see from the server explorer on the left its done on localhost, but when i try to publish it on azure only mvc web project is deployed. Just to be sure ive connected with sql management studio to azure database and it only shows Identity tables. After searching for few days online to find solution i gave up cuz they are all basic stuff.

Can u help me make that happen :D My goal is to deploy web application with class library(s) and 2 DbContexts using one database on azure.

Thank u very much.

link to pictures so u get better understanding of my problem

http://testic1.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: You need to change your database connection string (in web.config) to point to your azure SQL Server... Have you actually looked at any tutorials as this is a basic point?

Comment: yup i did, thank for answer. the thing is if i leave default con string it still works. i am kinda sure that con string is not problem. rather i thing i need to configure some other thing. just dont know what. application works as is. it just dont upload dal class library with that second db context

Comment: What do you mean it 'dont upload dal class library'? How do you know this? Post error message and part of code where you reference it...

Comment: i posted code below

Answer (score 0):

there is no error msg. at publish console i just get project published - 1 and thats it.

this is dbcontext from class library

```
namespace Quiz.DAL
{
    public class QuizContext : DbContext
    {
        public QuizContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Option> Options { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is dbcontext from mvc web application

```
namespace Quiz.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }   
        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

this is connection string from mvc web project, DAL class library does not have connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Quiz.mdf;Initial Catalog=Quiz;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Well if it is not referenced anywhere in the project you deployed it will not be deployed.... try using it in the main project and redeploy

Comment: i did reference it. however ive figure it out. this thing is u have to change change connection string name for every dbcontext both in base of the constructor and web.config.

Comment: ...The one in the base of the constructor isn't used if one is found in Web.Config, so as I said - you just have to change the connection string in web.config lol